# Dynamic Two Dimensional Array Creation Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a long string of repeating two hexadecimal characters separated by a space read in from a file that I would like to store into a two dimensional (array) list for processing later. The string is in the form:

file_content = "00 18 00 19 F0 0F 1A 80 FF C7 E8 11 7F 52 7D 00 F0 0D F0 0C 0B FF"

Each sub string that needs indexed begins with "00" and ends with "FF". There are no instances of "FF" mid string but there are instances of "00" possible which makes this tricky. I would like to store each one of these events to its own index in the list. For example:

event_list = [[00 18 00 19 F0 0F 1A 80 FF], [C7 E8 11 7F 52 7D 00 F0 0D F0 0C 0B FF], .....}

Comment: Hope the answer helped you, if you have more questions don't hesitate to let me know! :) Please consider marking the answer that you went for as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you're splitting it up based on the 'FF's present in the string, so you could probably get away with something like:

`event_list = [('%sFF' % x).strip().split(' ') for x in file_content.split('FF')[:-1]]`

This will split your original string by the 'FF's present, then loop through the split parts, append an ' FF' to the end of them. It then splits the new string by the space character, generating a new list and appends it to the outer list, creating the `2D array` you require in 1 line :)

Comment: Fixed that for compatibility

Comment: When testing the output I get is [['00', '18', '00', '19', 'F0', '0F', '1A', '80', 'FF'], ['', 'C7', 'E8', '11', '7F', '52', '7D', '00', 'F0', '0D', 'F0', '0C', '0B', 'FF']], which is a 2D array of strings, as the OP requested.